# Custom button groups

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I want to use foundation button groups and have my own styling, but i don't know how to set up the custom style foe chosen button

I have this:

```
.format-button-group {
  @include button-group-container(
    $styles:true

  );
  .format-group { @include button; }
}
```

How can I set up "active" button styles for the one that was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with radio group http://jsfiddle.net/vDyK2/

html:

```
<ul class="button-group round">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="btn1" name="btn">
        <label for="btn1" class="small button secondary">Ipsum</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="btn2" name="btn">
        <label for="btn2" class="small button secondary">Dolor</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="btn3" name="btn">
        <label for="btn3" class="small button secondary">Sit amet</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
.small.button.secondary{
    margin:0;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
    background-color: rgb(0, 114, 149);
}
```